# Printing 2 lists on one line

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print every first num from each list in one line, I wasted like 1 hour on it trying but didn't the solution

```
Xx = [1298, 1390, 1487, 1573, 1669, 1766, 1766, 1672, 1573, 1485, 1392, 1297, 1303, 1388, 1487, 1577, 1664, 1757, 1763, 1671,
      1577, 1487, 1393, 1298, 1301, 1376, 1449, 1535, 1604, 1682, 1760, 1769, 1676, 1568, 1485, 1398, 1300]

Yx = [331, 328, 328, 326, 329, 329, 422, 422, 416, 422, 419, 421, 514, 518, 516, 518, 518, 517, 605, 606, 605,
      603, 602, 605, 730, 737, 736, 738, 740, 740, 742, 858, 869, 860, 857, 863, 864]

for posX, posY in (Xx, Yx):
    print(posX, posY)
```

Error:
   for posX, posY in (Xx, Yx):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Did you intent to print number from each list in the same index together in one line? Or did you intent to get only the very first item of each list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intended to print numbers having same index from each list in the row together in one line and so on (going by your attempted code), you need to use zip:

```
for x, y in zip(Xx, Yx):
    print(x, y)
```

If you intended to print only the first item of each list (you mentioned something like that)

```
print(Xx[0], Yx[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

For iterating simultaneously in multiple list, you need `zip()`.
`zip` gives a `tuple` containing the iterators of all the lists given as parameters to it.

**Example: 1**

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
l3 = [7, 8, 9]

for l, m, n in zip(l1, l2, l3):
    print(l, m, n)
```

**Output:**

> 1 4 7
>   2 5 8
>   3 6 9

---

**Example: 2**

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
l3 = [7, 8, 9, 10]
l4 = [11, 12]

for l, m, n, o in zip(l1, l2, l3, l4):
    print(l, m, n, o)
```

**Output:**

> 1 4 7 11
>   2 5 8 12

**Note**: that in Example:2 lists `l3` and `l4` had an unequal number of elements. So, `zip` iterations are done only till the least number of elements of all the parameters li